# Java - Parser Library to parse a decimal to byte in x-bits

Tags: java, parsing, converters, 8-bit

I have a problem with parsers.

The problem is I get an integer such as "8" and I need to transform this to an 8-bit unsigned byte. 
Later on I will receive an integer "56" and need to transform it using the the same method but when I get a "-53" (for example) I shall say that was a mistake in the communication and sending.

For example,

```
number = 538; //or 63492873 or 8 or 17826312631 or -231 or whatever
try{
  byte response[] = Parse8BitUnsigned(number);
}catch(Idkexcepcion ex){
  System.out.println("the number is a signed one");
  byte response[] = Parse8BitSigned(number);
}
```

Note: Parse8BitSigned() and Parse8BitSigned() had not been implemented. I need that method for any number

Comment: What is your question and is `java.lang.Integer.valueOf("8")` the answer?

Comment: My question is, int to 8bit array in byte, like
byte response[] = Parse8Bit(8);

Comment: What you want is to parse **positive** values only, not `unsigned`. `unsigned` and `signed` is a representation. For instance signed byte range from [-128;127]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to do what you want:

```
String number="8";
int num = Integer.valueOf(number);
if(num < 0 ) //ERROR
// Return 8 in a 4 bytes array
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(num).array();
```